# VS2013 have to rebuild solution when project changes,Otherwise, there will be many mistakes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Detail：[image: Error image]

1. I just add a Field in my class,then build solution,but vs2013 tell me that I have many mistakses.But I rebuild the solution,it will success.
2. When I switched to a new computer, using vs2013 also had this problem.

3.in vs2017 do the same option,all is ok
4.the message is chinese,I don't know whether you can understand the information.

[output detail image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOpba.png)

Thanks for helping me,I love you all,I love stack Overflow.Forgive my poor English！

Comment: When you have a project referencing another, make sure to add a project reference rather than referencing the contents of the `bin\debug` folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2017 (see "Project-to-project references")

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you reference some dll not again builded by VisualStudio ?

---

In the case where your solution has two projects : A and B. 
Normally, when you want to add reference of dll fromproject A to your project B : you must add the project A in B ("Projects option" in "Reference manager" of VisualStudio) and not directly the dll of project A in project B ("Browse option" in "Reference manager" of VisualStudio ).

---

With "Add project", VisualStudio build project A and after project B.
But with "Add dll reference", VisualStudio think the dll is already available so it is necessary to build twice.

Comment: Note that the second scenario *can* work, by setting a project dependency so that Visual Studio will know that it needs to build that project first (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2017). But there's no point in doing that since project references take care of everything automatically

Comment: i have too many project,some days ago all is ok,but when my colleagues move the solution to new place,then i found this problem.I don't think it's dll reference problem，In vs2017,do the same operation， all is ok

Comment: Do you use Nuget package ? Perhasp, it is a difficulty to restore Nuget packages. With VS2017, there are automatic mechanism. And it depends if you use Nuget with  "Package reference" or "Package config".

Comment: We have not enough information. Can you give us the output of build ?

Comment: i update the information,but some Information is chinese,i don't know how to show you English Language information，so sorry

Comment: I use Nuget package.Is it possible that the. Net Framework version is different?

Comment: I don't think so. The used .Net framework is defined in the project properties. Is the same computer with VS 2017 and VS 2013 ? How is installed the .Net framework (installer or nuget package) ?